# How to efficiently export one neo4j database to another one?

Tags: neo4j

Having two neo4j database A and B, I want to append A with B. How to deal with it?

Comment: If this is a use case in your application, please explain more about what you want to accomplish. If it's about backup, use the existing support for [incremental backups](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/operations-backup.html).

Comment: It seems that the BatchInserter and GraphDatabaseService can't be initialized at the same time, since both of them try to lock the same copy of the database files. As an alternative, one database(said A) is started with the server. then if a batch request arrives, server just starts an other DB(said B) for batch insert. when the batch job finished, just append database A with B(the data stored in A and B is disjoint)

Comment: You can't use the BatchInserter and GraphDatabaseService at the same time. There's no "append" operation, so what you can do is to code up something for reading from the B database and copy it to A. But why don't you simply write the batch request data to A in a separate thread in the first place?

Comment: It seems that the file lock could not be shared by different threads.

Comment: Just use the same GraphDatabaseService instance in the different threads, don't create new instances.

Answer (score 0):

i have NOT used this, but came across it this morning investigating gremlin.

http://tinkerpop.com/maven2/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/0.5/api/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/pgm/util/GraphHelper.html

check out the copyGraph(Graph from, Graph to)
          Copy the vertex/edges of one graph over to another graph.